# Python ModuleNotFoundError in Flask tutorial

Tags: python, flask, import, module

I was following this python Flask tutorial [here](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iii-web-forms).

I got to the stage where my file structure looks like this but when I try and run the application the `__init__.py` file can't find the config module.

```
.
|__ project
    |__ src
       |__ application.py
       |__ app
          |__ __init__.py
          |__ config.py
          |__ forms.py
          |__ routes.py
```

```
Error: While importing "application", an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\alex_\desktop\website\eb-flask\virt\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 235, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Alex_\Desktop\website\eb-flask\application.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import app as application
  File "C:\Users\Alex_\Desktop\website\eb-flask\app\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from config import Config
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your config.py is in the wrong file. It should not be inside app file but where the application.py is. 
This is what Miguel has done as well, you can see, in his github for this lesson that you gave a link to. 
https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/microblog/tree/v0.3

Hope this helps!

Comment: let me know if my solution worked! if so, I would be glad you accepted it.